# Get last row of each group with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a query like this:

```
DECLARE @DeadDesigns AS TABLE(
 LegacyKey INT
,DesignKey INT
,StatusKey INT
,DesignGroupId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
INSERT INTO @DeadDesigns
SELECT [P].[LegacyKey],[D].DesignKey, [D].[StatusKey], [D].[DesignGroupId] FROM Project AS P
INNER JOIN DesignGroup AS DG ON P.ProjectKey = DG.ProjectKey
INNER JOIN Design AS D ON DG.DesignGroupId  = D.DesignGroupId
WHERE [D].[StatusKey] = 67 --DEAD 

;WITH CTE2 (LegacyKey, DesignKey, StatusKey, DesignGroupId, RN) AS (
SELECT LegacyKey, DesignKey, StatusKey, DesignGroupId,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [LegacyKey], [DesignGroupId] ORDER BY [DesignGroupId]) AS RN
FROM @DeadDesigns 
    GROUP BY [DesignGroupId],[LegacyKey],DesignKey,StatusKey
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

Structure is:

One `LegacyKey` can have multiple `DesignGroupId` and one `DesignGroupId` can have multiple `DesignKey`

Objective is to get last `DesignKey` of each `DesignGroupId` separated from project

Wrong result:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
| LegacyKey | DesignKey | StatusKEy |            DesignGroupId             | RN |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
|     14002 |      2416 |        67 | 1A07C80E-E5E2-45F0-A5D2-419BAF3DC106 |  1 |
|     14002 |      2819 |        70 | 1A07C80E-E5E2-45F0-A5D2-419BAF3DC106 |  2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
```

This is wrong because it is the same DesignGroupId, if that DesignGroupId was different result was correct.

Detailed desire result:

I want to separate it by `DesignGroupId` so if have two different `DesignGroupId` and it's the same `LegacyKey` `RN` of second row should be 2.. if we have 3 `DesignGroupId` but same `LegacyKey`  `RN` of second row should be 3 and so on. At the end I want to get ALL last `DesignKey` inside each `DesignGroupId` inside each `LegacyKey`

What am I doing wrong?

Another example

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
| LegacyKey | DesignKey | StatusKEy |            DesignGroupId             | RN |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
|     18288 |      3974 |        63 | F18320D8-C7A8-4A2A-AFDE-38A483C24E81 |  1 |
|     18288 |      4096 |       107 | F18320D8-C7A8-4A2A-AFDE-38A483C24E81 |  2 |
|     18288 |      7224 |        66 | F18320D8-C7A8-4A2A-AFDE-38A483C24E81 |  3 |
|     18288 |      4842 |        66 | A18320D8-C7A8-4A2A-AFDE-38A483C24E81 |  1 |
|     18289 |      7325 |        66 | 90C224D9-2514-4294-8DEC-D3EE16EC2D00 |  1 |
|     18289 |      3975 |        63 | 90C224D9-2514-4294-8DEC-D3EE16EC2D00 |  2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
```

In this case I have two different `LegacyKey` but result is wrong because it returns all `RN` of same `DesignGroupId` and I only want last one. Desire result is:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
| LegacyKey | DesignKey | StatusKEy |            DesignGroupId             | RN |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
|     18288 |      7224 |        66 | F18320D8-C7A8-4A2A-AFDE-38A483C24E81 |  3 |
|     18288 |      4842 |        66 | A18320D8-C7A8-4A2A-AFDE-38A483C24E81 |  1 |
|     18289 |      3975 |        63 | 90C224D9-2514-4294-8DEC-D3EE16EC2D00 |  2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----+
```

As you can see I get last `RN` of `DesignGroupId`, but they are in the same `LegacyKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect a `GROUP BY` in the subquery.  And I would expect filtering in the outer query:

```
WITH CTE2 (LegacyKey, DesignKey, StatusKey, DesignGroupId, RN) AS (
      SELECT LegacyKey, DesignKey, StatusKey, DesignGroupId,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [LegacyKey], [DesignGroupId] ORDER BY [DesignGroupId] DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM @DeadDesigns 
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note that I changed the `ORDER BY` to `DESC` -- that is typical when you want the "last" or "most recent" of something.