# Select all rows except last one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query where I have `RowNumber()` function, so I have row number by a partition in the result.

What do I want to achieve? I want to update all row numbers of each partition except the last row of each partition. So suppose we have RowNumber `1,2,3,4` and another partition with `1,2` I want to do an update clause to update all row numbers except number `4`(first partition) and exclude row number `2` of the second partition.

I know we can exclude first row number using a simple condition in where clause like `RowNumber != 1` but in this case, I want the last row number of each partition and that number is different in all partitions .

How can I achieve this? Regards

Comment: This was in the solution to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730698/get-last-row-of-each-group-with-cte).

Comment: Generic version of this question: [SQL Selecting all BUT the last row in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19470230/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an updatable CTE, but reverse the direction of the `order by` in `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      < your query here but with DESC sort instead of ASC sort or vice versa >
     )
update toupdate
    set . . .
    where rownumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any SQL.
As per your question i can think of putting your result in a subquery and using the max of RowNumber. 
Or better provide some sql and sample data for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the `ORDER BY` clause from `ASC to DESC` or `DESC to ASC` as per the requirement and you can continue updating as

```
Where RowNumber != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work too:

```
  with temptbl as (
     select *,max(rn) over (partition by id order by somethingelse) rnmax from dbo.yourtable
     )
update temptbl
    set [whatever you plan on updating]
    where rn=rnmax;
```

Answer (score 0):

As many other suggested, turn the order on its head would make it much simpler as row 1 would be the row you don't want to update.

Just make sure to use

```
....
,row_number() over(partition by TEMP1 order by TEMP2 desc[or asc])
....

where rn <> 1
```

and you should be on the right path.